# MS Access Form events, VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have 3 fields in an access form.

- Field 1 - is a text field pre-populated with some data. There are no null records
- Field 2 - is a text field pre-populated with some data. It can either have a value or be null.
- Field 3 - Is a text field. The user will enter information into the field.

There is a rule. If there is a null value in field 2, then field 3 will equal the value from field 1 and so I want it to automatically populate field 3 from field 1. if the value is not null, then the user will populate the field record manually.

I have set up a form load event to:

```
If Me.field2 = "" Then
   Me.field3 = Me.field1
```

The problem I am having is, the user may want to change the pre-populated value of field 1 and if the corresponding field 2 record is blank, I want field 3 to be updated with the same value the user changed in field 1. I don't want to have to reload the form all the time for this update to occur. I've tried the above syntax in a After_Update event and a change event, but it's not updating.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: One way to go is to put your check mechanism into a little sub, similar to what you have already. Call this sub from form_load() and maybe even from form_current if needed. You can then call it in the field1_AfterUpdate event.

Comment: I'm not sure who entered an answer a few minutes ago, but the 'If (IsNull(Me.DEV_TYPE) Or Me.DEV_TYPE = "") Then' worked for me. It disappeared as an answer, but thanks.

Comment: Use `IsNull(Me.Field2.Value) or Me.Field2.Value=""`

Comment: Although you already have an answer, you could also just check the length rather than testing for null or an empty string: `If Len(Me.Field2.Value) = 0 Then`

Comment: @creamyegg - doesn't `Len(null)` return null ?  Maybe: `If Len(Nz([Me.Field2.Value],"")) = 0`

Comment: @Tim /creamegg Len(null) gives you an "Invalid use of Null" error.

Comment: My test was `x = Len(Null)`. but it seems that gives the same result as `x= null` - so yes, @Tim is right len(null) does return null.

Comment: @TimWilliams My mistake, I'm more use to dealing with Excel (where the `.Value` property always returns a string) rather than Access. This is what it should be in the Access world: `Len(Format(Me.Field1.Value))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike's already got his answer, but I'll give a fuller answer in the form of an explanation.

The problem here is that you are trying to compare a field that is `null` to an empty string. It's like you've done

```
if null = "" then
    'do stuff
end if
```

The problem is when `null` is used in a comparison, the result is always null - which causes the `if` to evaluate to false. You can't even do this:

```
if not(null) then
    'do stuff
end if
```

or

```
if not (null <> "") then
    'do stuff
end if
```

The conventional solution is to us `isnull(x)`, which evaluates to `true` if  `x` is `null`.

As Tim Williams indicate, you can use:

```
IsNull(x) or x=""
```

Some might consider the `x=""` to be redundant if `x` can only return null for an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

another test for empty string or null is

```
if len(field1 & "")=0 then 'do null stuff
```

appending an empty string to null or an empty string results in an empty string, which you can then test for length

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
if Nz(Field1, "") <> "" then 'do null / empty stuff
```